# Who ordered the gates to be shut in Fal Dara?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

When Rand learns that the Amyrylin had arrived he immediately packs his bags and attempts to leave because of Lan's advice. However, he is unable to do so because the Gateguards and Stable has been told that no one may leave Fal Dara.

In both instances it is especially pointed out if it is "Lord Agelmar's Order".
Since Lord Agelmar didn't give the order until he heard Fain had escaped and Horn of Valere had been stolen.

So who was it actually who ordered the gates to be closed so no one could go out?

Comment: I edited out the tag [tag:the-great-hunt] because we don’t seem to have enough questions specifically about events from this book to justify having a tag for it in addition to [tag:wheel-of-time]. Feel free to revert if the edit goes too far, though.

Comment: I created the tag wiki, pending for approval. Maybe we can retag some if needed. Only added because I'd seen tags for some books like Memory of light.

Comment: I couldn't find anything specific, but I am pretty certain it was Liandrin.

Comment: @DaveJohnson I've always thought Lanfear was the "intuitive" answer. A big deal is made of the fact that "only Agelmar can give such an order", from which I infer that whoever gave the order probably used Compulsion. Now, Liandrin has the means and motive, but very little opportunity. I don't think she would have had time to slip away from the Amyrlin's entourage to compel the guards. Lanfear seems to be the only option left.

Comment: Well, it was probably Ingtar, who relayed it through Uno and maybe others. It could be one of his "darkfriend tasks".